# windows fileopen multiple file order

Tags: windows

Anyone knows how to select multiple files in correct order in a standard windows fileopen dialog?
Shift-click and control-click, i never get the correct order.

The last file ctrl-clicked seems to become the first in the resulting selected files-list, but not always.

i want to click in order:
1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg
to become
"1.jpg" "2.jpg" "3.jpg" "4.jpg"

same question was asked here http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/509803-cmdialog-file-open-multiple-file-selection-order but the link mentioned is dead by now. :(

I'm using html5 multifile upload, and would like to have the items uploaded in the order the user selected them in the openfiledialog.

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the order. The last file clicked always goes to the front. I do not know of any exceptions to this rule.

Comment: try ctrl click 4321 then click whitespace and try another order... here it isn't correct reversed

Comment: I tried it with files named 1.txt, 2.txt and 3.txt. All it takes is to reverse the order...

Comment: Did that work? or did you mean something else?

Comment: sometimes it's exactly reversed, but sometimes it's random. I guess i'll have to implement reordering after upload. Thanks.